# Why does this only print "Will you see the target?"?

Tags: java, html, servlets

Caller servlet:

```
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res) throws ServletException, IOException {
    res.setContentType("text/html");
    PrintWriter out = res.getWriter();
    out.println("<HTML>");
    out.println("<BODY>Will you see the source?");
    out.println("</BODY></HTML>");
    RequestDispatcher disp=req.getRequestDispatcher("/Test");
    disp.forward(req, res);
    out.close();
}

("/Test"):
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
    throws ServletException, IOException {
    response.setContentType("text/html");
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    out.println("<HTML><TITLE>The Test</TITLE>");
    out.println("<BODY>Will you see the target?");
    out.println("</BODY></HTML>");
    out.close();
}
```

Why does this only print "Will you see the target?"? Shouldn't it print "Will you see the source?" too since the PrintWriter is placed before the forward?

Comment: From the doc of `forward`: "This method allows one servlet to do preliminary processing of a request and another resource to generate the response" (see https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/RequestDispatcher.html#forward(javax.servlet.ServletRequest,%20javax.servlet.ServletResponse) )

Answer (score 1):

**Read the documentation**, i.e. the javadoc of [`forward`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/RequestDispatcher.html#forward(javax.servlet.ServletRequest,%20javax.servlet.ServletResponse)):

> `forward` should be called before the response has been committed to the client (before response body output has been flushed). If the response already has been committed, this method throws an `IllegalStateException`. **Uncommitted output in the response buffer is automatically cleared before the forward**.

Answer (score 0):

It actually prints the "Will you see the source?" text.But after printing the RequestDispatcher is initialized and is forward() is called to "/Test" .Doing so will forward the request to URL "/Test" thus loading a new page.